# Show that $\sigma^2$ is a Cycle iff the length of $\sigma$ is Odd

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I got this question. I'm totally stumped and I don't know what to do.

> Let $\sigma$ be a cycle of length $k > 2$. Show that $\sigma^2$ is a cycle iff $k$ is odd.

Comment: Write down what $\sigma^2$ does when $\sigma$ is a cycle of length $3,4,5,6,\dotsc$. You should spot the pattern.

Answer (score 6):

Assume to contrary, let $\sigma=(a_1a_2\cdots a_{2k})$. Then $\sigma^2=(a_1a_3\cdots a_{2k-1})(a_2a_4\cdots a_{2k})$ and it is a contradiction. Conversely, Assume that $\sigma=(a_1a_2\cdots a_{2k+1})$. It is not hard to see that $(a_1a_3\cdots a_{2k+1}a_2a_4\cdots a_{2k})$.

Answer (score 3):

For the reverse direction, if $k$ is even, then $\sigma^2$ consists of two cycles, namely the even and odd positions of the original cycle (written in cycle notation).  For example, if $\sigma=(1~2~3~4~5~6)$, then $\sigma^2=(1~3~5)(2~4~6)$.  Perhaps this will give you some insight into the forward direction.